# Change window opacity when opening a form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings, opacity

I'm trying to change a Form's opacity automatically before loading.
I am using built in Settings function to save the value what opacity the window should have.
The problem is, when I'm debugging my application, it all works well, when I compile it and try to open the executable, the window just dissapears... I don't get any errors.

This is how I'm trying to do it:

First there is a value in settings called *opacity* (int) from 0-100

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.opacity * 0.01;
    }
```

Comment: What value do you have in your settings?  I created a windows app, set opacity to 50, copied the .exe to the desktop and ran it without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you debug, the settings that you save will be kept from run to run. When you deploy, it will copy the default settings file.

Do a check to see if the settings file opacity is actually being loaded correctly when you run the release exe. I have a feeling that either the default is 0, or it's not being loaded.

Comment: I had same idea... I can change the value from my built in settings and it writes the xml file just fine... with right values.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the Opacity value has 1.0 as fully visible, and 0.0 as fully invisible. Anything above 1.0 counts as fully visible, too.

---

**EDIT**

ok, so after re-reading your question... maybe instead of using the default, use a constant like 0.5 to test it.

Comment: I know that. The problem is when I run the exe, the window doesnt open at all. Only icon on taskbar. When I debug it, it work perfectly...